# Ruby if statement - how to avoid multiple elsif statements including not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, syntax, coding-style

I am creating a piece of functionality to auto generate descriptions based on attributes I have on properties (in a Rails app).

I have created a series of service classes to handle this - here is

```
class RoomDescriptionGeneratorInternetTV <  RoomDescriptionGeneratorBase

  def generate
    if internet? && cable_tv?
      internet_and_cable_tv_sentence
    elsif internet? && tv? && !cable_tv?
      internet_and_tv_sentence
    elsif internet? && !tv? && !cable_tv?
      internet_sentence
    end
  end

  private

  def internet?
    room.internet (#refers to an active record column in the room model)
  end

  def cable_tv?
    room.cable_tv
  end

  def tv?
    room.tv
  end

  # The sentences are then held in the locales for translation purposes.
  def internet_sentence
    t("internet")
  end

  def internet_and_tv_sentence
    t("internet_and_tv")
  end

  def internet_and_cable_tv_sentence
    t("internet_and_cable_tv")
  end
```

The the purpose of this code is to generate sentence which reads "This property has [internet], and [cable TV], [TV]" if of course these property has these attributes. The use of this sentence and the instantuation of this class however happens in a separate Service Object using:

```
class RoomDescriptionGenerator < RoomDescriptionGeneratorBase
  #Other code...

  def internet_tv
    RoomDescriptionGeneratorInternetTV.new(room,locale).generate
  end

end
```

The use if/elsif statments combined with not(!) just seems horrible. I am looking for clearer ways to refactor this to achieve my aim of generating the correct sentences based on the attributes.

Comment: Have a look at the Builder Pattern: http://rorandme.blogspot.nl/2012/02/some-simple-design-patterns-in-ruby.html

Comment: Just try to use below:    
    if internet? && cable_tv? return internet_and_cable_tv_sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that some of the conditions are useless. For example you test for `!cable_tv?` in the second condition, but if `cable_tv?` was `true` then the first condition would have been `true`alreday. Similar situation in the last condition.

Furthermore you check for `internet?` in every condition. One check upfront would be more efficient.

I would rewrite the block to something like:

```
def generate
  return unless internet? 

  case
  when cable_tv? then internet_and_cable_tv_sentence
  when tv?       then internet_and_tv_sentence
  else                internet_sentence
  end
end
```

Note that I prefer a `case when` blocks over a `if elsif` blocks for readablity reasons

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
def generate
  return internet_and_cable_tv_sentence if internet? && cable_tv? 
  return internet_and_tv_sentence if internet? && tv? && !cable_tv? 
  return internet_sentence if internet? && !tv? && !cable_tv? 
end
```